# separate float/double/integer from column values

Tags: python, regex, pandas

How can I separate float/double/integer from string. basically there are column values in a pandas df.
e.g:

```
150.39999389648438cfm
0.30000001192092896inHO
63.70000076293945%
73.0999984741211F
85.9000015258789kW
75.5F
100%
44S
32F
false
NA
true
```

my result set would be the values without any alphabets/special chars.

```
150.39999389648438
0.30000001192092896
63.70000076293945
73.0999984741211
85.9000015258789
75.5
100
44
32
false

true
```

currently i am using re for this. but i am looking for something more optimized.

```
def is_alphanumeric(inst):
    return re.search("(\d)+.(\d)+[a-z]+$", inst)
is_alphanumeric(str(df.iloc[0][i])):
            df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].apply(lambda x:float(''.join(ele for ele in x if ele.isdigit() or ele == '.')))


is_percentage(str(df.iloc[0][i])):
df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].apply(lambda x:float(''.join(ele for  ele  in  x  if  ele.isdigit()  or  ele == '.')))
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to strip off non-numeric chars from the end. You may do it with `\D+$` regex.

Comment: as @WiktorStribiżew has suggested you can do this using `replace`: `df[col].astype(str).str.replace('(\D+$)()','')`

Comment: along with such values i also have boolean values true and false. so i have to make sure that these values are not changed

Comment: this is not working. df.iloc[:, i].astype(str).str.replace('((true|false)|\D+$)()', '')

Comment: If you use above regex, you must replace with `r'\2'`, not with an empty string. And you must add another argument - `inplace=True`

Comment: @occasionalvisitor edit your question and include the true and false values in the string like they appear in your column and update the desired result as well.

Comment: hi @EdChum, this is not working for skipping true and false. pdsDF.iloc[:, i].astype(str).str.replace('((true|false)|\D+$)()', r'\2').inplace = True. can you tell what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

- Search for: `^.*?\b(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|true|false))\b.*?$`
- Replace with: `$1`

**Explanation:**

```
^                   : start of string
.*?                 : 0 or more any char
\b                  : word boundary
(?:                 : non capture group
  (                 : group 1
    \d+(?:\.\d+)?   : an integer or a float
    |               : or
    true            : true
    |               : or
    false           : false
  )                 : end group 1
)                   : end group
\b                  : word boundary
.*?                 : 0 or more any char
$                   : end of string
```